# Partitioned dataframe / reshape and stacking

Tags: r, partitioning, data-manipulation, reshape2, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe which basically is portioned like this:

```
Geo <- c("AGE", "region1", "region2", "region3")
y1 <- c("total", 1:3)
y2 <- c(NA, 4:6)
y3 <- c(NA, 7:9)
df <- data.frame(Geo, y1, y2, y3)

Geo <- c("AGE", "region1", "region2", "region3")
y1 <- c("60 years", 9:11)
y2 <- c(NA,12:14)
y3 <- c(NA,15:17)
df2 <- data.frame(Geo,y1,y2,y3)

# shape 
df <- rbind(df,df2)
```

So, my dataframe looks like this:

```
    Geo       y1 y2 y3
1     AGE    total NA NA
2 region1        1  4  7
3 region2        2  5  8
4 region3        3  6  9
5     AGE 60 years NA NA
6 region1        9 12 15
7 region2       10 13 16
8 region3       11 14 17
```

As you can observe my dataframe is essentially portioned in two parts, where with "AGE" being the effective row that partitions this dataframe. I want to unstack this blocks and put them in a working format like this:

**My scope**

```
   Geo year value      Age
1  region1   y1     1    total
2  region1   y2     4    total
3  region1   y3     7    total
4  region2   y1     2    total
5  region2   y2     5    total
6  region2   y3     8    total
7  region3   y1     3    total
8  region3   y2     6    total
9  region3   y3     9    total
10 region1   y1     9 60 years
11 region1   y2    12 60 years
12 region1   y3    15 60 years
13 region2   y1    10 60 years
14 region2   y2    13 60 years
15 region2   y3    16 60 years
16 region3   y1    11 60 years
17 region3   y2    14 60 years
18 region3   y3    17 60 years
```

Can someone just a quick and efficient way of doing this as my original dataframe constrains thousands of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your data is a bit of a nightmare! It can be done relatively easily using some basic `dplyr` munging and `tidyr` tools as follows,

```
Geo<-c("AGE","region1","region2","region3")
y1 <-c("total",1:3)
y2 <-c(NA,4:6)
y3 <-c(NA,7:9)
df<-data.frame(Geo,y1,y2,y3)

Geo<-c("AGE","region1","region2","region3")
y1 <-c("60 years",9:11)
y2 <-c(NA,12:14)
y3 <-c(NA,15:17)
df2<-data.frame(Geo,y1,y2,y3)

# shape 
df <- rbind(df,df2)

## Add age as a variable - this assumes the same number of regions for all ages
## Find all age rows and pull unique age values
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)

ages <- df %>% 
  filter(Geo %in% "AGE") %>% 
  pull(y1)

no_regions <- df %>% 
  filter(grepl("region", Geo)) %>% 
  pull(Geo) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  length()

# Add age variable, drop Age blocks, gather variables, and arrange data
df_tidy <- df %>% 
  mutate(age = ages %>% 
           as.character %>% 
           map(rep, no_regions + 1) %>% 
           unlist) %>% 
  filter(!(Geo %in% "AGE")) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", y1, y2, y3) %>% 
  arrange(desc(age), Geo)
```

*Note: This solution only works if there are the same number of regions for each age group. If this is not the case something more complex will be required (something like adding a variable at each age break and then looping through adding the age variable) if this is the case let me know and I will edit the answer.*

**Improvements**

Based on Jaap's great base R answer I have generalised my `tidyverse` solution. This now works regardless of the number of regions, `zoo::na.locf` is a great function!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
library(zoo)


df_tidy <- df %>% 
  mutate(age = ifelse(Geo %in% "AGE", as.character(.$y1), NA) %>% 
           na.locf) %>% 
  filter(!(Geo %in% "AGE")) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -Geo, -age) %>% 
  arrange(desc(age), Geo)
```

This gives the following:

[image: Required output]

Comment: Do I also have to create a new column named 'age' here ? Your solution seems very promising but so far cannot make it work in my large dataframe.

Comment: No the answer should make that for you. What error etc are you getting?

Comment: I made this modification of your code to match my data characteristics 'vec<-noquote(names(data)[2:length(data)])

df_tidy <- data %>% 
  mutate(age = ifelse(Geo %in% "AGE", as.character(2013), NA) %>% 
           na.locf) %>% 
  filter(!(Geo %in% "AGE")) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", vec) %>% 
  arrange(desc(age), Geo)'  ... but sadly the columns `age' and 'value' are the same

Comment: It might be an issue with your column name `2013` being used as a number. Hard to see without your output. I have edited the answer to make it safer. Give it a try?

Comment: If it still isn't working could you add the error/message it gives you as a screen shot along with the a screenshot of the output.

Comment: No error but, the `age' and `variable' columns in the example give me identical values in my case. If I have to describe what my column names my looks like, I would say those are names something like --> c (Geo, as.character(2013:2035) )

Comment: Did my changes help? The other issue I see is that you are trying to gather over all variables names in your data. Try the updated solution, just adding `2013` in place of `y1`. If it still isn't working I would suggest adding a snapshot of the actual variables names in your data.

Comment: It looks that it worked, but I had to do `$'2013'`. Looks that there is a shortcoming in R if column names are `numbers'.

Comment: Great. Yes although not really a shortcoming, you really want it to default to being a number for numbers. Just refer to them with `\`year\`` in future

Answer (score 3):

A solution in base R (with a little bit of `zoo`):

```
# creat a new 'age' column with only values in the rows
# that have an 'age'-value in `y1`
df$age[df$Geo == "AGE"] <- as.character(df$y1[df$Geo == "AGE"])

# fill the missing values with 'na.locf' from the 'zoo'-package
df$age <- zoo::na.locf(df$age)

# filter out the rows with "AGE" in 'Geo'
df <- df[df$Geo != "AGE",]

# now convert 'y1' to integers
df$y1 <- as.integer(as.character(df$y1))

# reshape into long format and set the rownames to just a numeric index
df2 <- reshape(df, direction = "long", idvar = c("Geo","age"),
               varying = c("y1","y2","y3"), timevar = 'year',
               v.names = "value", times = c("y1","y2","y3"))
rownames(df2) <- NULL
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df2
>        Geo      age year value
> 1  region1    total   y1     1
> 2  region2    total   y1     2
> 3  region3    total   y1     3
> 4  region1 60 years   y1     9
> 5  region2 60 years   y1    10
> 6  region3 60 years   y1    11
> 7  region1    total   y2     4
> 8  region2    total   y2     5
> 9  region3    total   y2     6
> 10 region1 60 years   y2    12
> 11 region2 60 years   y2    13
> 12 region3 60 years   y2    14
> 13 region1    total   y3     7
> 14 region2    total   y3     8
> 15 region3    total   y3     9
> 16 region1 60 years   y3    15
> 17 region2 60 years   y3    16
> 18 region3 60 years   y3    17
> ```

Comment: This is great. Could you add a few comments explaining the steps? I always reflexively reach for the `tidyverse` toolkit.

Comment: Your answer was great, but not as general as @SamAbbott. One problem that I figure out in my database, which was not the case with the other answer, is that the reshape function is sensitive to duplicate elements. In may case I had a couple of them.

Comment: @msh855 no problem, I just wanted to show that there are different ways to tackle a problem